# g++ compiler giving me extra qualification error?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a school assignment in C++, and I've implemented a header file with a constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Shopper
{
    public:
    Shopper::Shopper(int yrs_a_mbr, double av_mnth_prchs, char* sh_nm);

    int years_a_member;
    double avg_month_purchases;
    double membership_cost;
    double nominal_membership_cost;

    private:
};
```

Whenever I compile, the compiler gives me an error saying "extra qualification error" on the line

```
Shopper::Shopper(int yrs_a_mbr, double av_mnth_prchs, char* sh_nm);
```

I've looked at various examples and I still can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Omit the `Shopper::`, you don't specify the class until you provide the implementation.

Comment: I've already tried this unfortunetely, it gives me a plethora of errors regarding something something relocation has invalid index..

Comment: Show your associated source code...

Comment: @Jan.Jedrasik that other message is a linker error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix (or maybe you need to define `main`)

Comment: Please show is the file which you compile, that includes this header.

Comment: "Relocation has invalid index" is a linker error most commonly seen when you don't define a `main()` function...

Comment: Omitting `Shopper::` is the correct answer to the question you have posted. If you get other errors then they are a different issue; you should accept the answer posted by sehe here and ask a new question about the other errors. (if you can't solve them first of course..)

Answer (score 1):

> @Jan.Jedrasik that other message is a linker error. See [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) (or maybe you need to define `main`)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/841fb302ccf3a6b5)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Shopper {
  public:
    Shopper(int yrs_a_mbr, double av_mnth_prchs, char const*sh_nm) : years_a_member(yrs_a_mbr),
        avg_month_purchases(av_mnth_prchs),
        membership_cost(0), nominal_membership_cost(0)
    {}

    int years_a_member;
    double avg_month_purchases;
    double membership_cost;
    double nominal_membership_cost;

  private:
};

int main() {
    Shopper big(1, 17, "John Doe");
}
```

Hints:

1. use `std::string`
2. don't store values that are derivatives
3. perhaps store the tariff information outside the Shopper (unless you're sure that shopper *have* their own individual (nominal) fees?)